# One line stops script C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Some part of the code works (`hp1 -= damage1;`), but the second part doesn't work.
Where did I make a mistake?

Here are parts of two scripts:

**Player1.cs**

```
private Bullet1 b1;

void Start()
{
    b1 = FindObjectOfType<Bullet1>();
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Bullet1")
    {
        hp1 -= damage1; // it works, my player loses hp
        Destroy1(); // doesn't work
    }
}

void Destroy1()
{
    b1.hit1 = true; // hit for bullet1.cs
}
```

**Bullet1.cs**

```
public bool hit1;

void Update()
{
    if (hit1)
    {
        hit1 = false;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

If I switch `bool hit = true` in real time in Unity, destroying works. It means that `Bullet1.cs` can't recieve `hit = true;`

*If* I swap lines `hp1 -= damage1;` **and** `Destroy1();`, my player can't get damage.   So, `Destroy1();` stops my code and then can't activate other lines. Also if I change `Destroy1();` to `b1.hit1 = true;` nothing new happens.

Comment: Is there any error in the console when this happens? A null reference exception perhaps? If so, we will need to see that error.

Comment: Sounds like `b1` is null to me. You're not checking for that.

Comment: In the start of your player you are grabbing a reference to the bullet object, but then in your bullet object you destroy the bullet. Your code logic in this is all very odd. You should instead just have a call to destroy the bullet through the collision detection directly. Put `Destroy(col.gameobject)` inside your collision detection in the player instead of doing whatever you're doing with the boolean.

Comment: @AlexMyers 1) `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayerController.Destroy2 () (at Assets/Scripts/Game/PlayerController.cs:255)
PlayerController.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D col) (at Assets/Scripts/Game/PlayerController.cs:116)` 2) `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayerController.Destroy2 () (at Assets/Scripts/Game/PlayerController.cs:255)`

Comment: 254-256: `void Destroy2()
    {
        b2.hit2 = true;
    }`

Comment: 116: `if (col.gameObject.tag == "Bullet1")
            {
                lasthit = 1f;
                hp1 -= damage1;
                Destroy1(); // 116 line
            }`

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant information (like the `NullReferenceException`) instead of adding it to the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just destroy the bullet through the collision instead of using the boolean. It's creating unnecessary resource usage. Of the given code, this is all you need to do to destroy the bullet using the player script. The parts of the bullet script shown are unnecessary. If you want additional logic handled inside the bullet when destroyed then use a [OnDestroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html) function to handle it.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Bullet1")
    {
        hp1 -= damage1;
        Destroy(col.gameobject); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use bigger code in `Bullet1.cs` when bullet collides. Like Instantiate animation and activate sound. So I need to change `bool` in `Bullet1.cs`

Comment: @ЯрославСмирнов I added a link to the OnDestroy function on how to handle that. It calls the function when given the Destroy command as a final set of instructions to perform before destroying the object.